# Can't set rigth resolution on yocto linux for lvds screen

Tags: linux, screen-resolution

I'm trying to set an 640x480 resolution on yocto linux by means of u-boot args giving the following parameter:

```
videomode=mxcfb0:dev=ldb,640x480p@60,if=RGB666
```

or using

```
videomode=mxcfb0:dev=ldb,LDB-VGA-NL,if=RGB666
```

but both the parameters do not work:
i get the right vertical resolution ,but the horizontal one is bigger,
i can see about 3/4 of the horizontal screen.

Instead if i boot with a higher resolution let's say WVGS (800x600),
I can fix the issue through xrandr giving the following command:

xrandr --fb 640x480

the screen gets the right resolution,anyway after the command i get the xrandr message

```
specified screen 640x480 not large enough for output DISP3 BG (800x480+0+0)
```

in the first case(600x480 boot parameters),even if i give the xrandr command nothing change.
Can i obtain the rigth resolution without booting with a higher one and then giving the xrandr --fb 640x480 command?

I did try to put a boot script in the etc/init.d folder ,but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Verify your display timings (hactive, vactive and others) according to your targeted resolution.

Ex:

```
lvds-channel@0 {
    fsl,data-mapping = "spwg";
    fsl,data-width = <24>;
    crtc = "ipu1-di0";
    reg = <0>;
    primary;
    status = "okay";
    display-timings {
        native-mode = <&timing1>;
        timing0: dgt4 {
            clock-frequency = <61627500>;
            ****hactive = <1280>; 
            vactive = <720>;****
            hback-porch = <250>;
            hfront-porch = <75>;
            vback-porch = <20>;
            vfront-porch = <5>;
            hsync-len = <40>;
            vsync-len = <5>;
            linux,phandle = <&timing0>;
```

The command what you give from boot mode/kernel command is for frame buffer, but the not for the display hardware.

Adjust the timing parameter of lvds according to the targeted display resolution.